# nginx two location same backends but different port

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two upstream

```
upstream app1{
    ip_hash;
    server  server1:9001;
    server  server2:9001;
}

upstream app2{
    ip_hash;
    server  server1:7001;
    server  server2:7001;
}
```

in the server config

```
location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://app1;
}
location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://app2;
}
```

each upstream have his own ip_hash. but i need that the ip of backend choosed by first location remains the same for location app2. the two ip_hash must choose the same ip of backend but with different port number.

the client start with the location served by app1, later he can add a request of location served by upstream app2.